# When is peach season?

Tags: fruits, peaches, fall-gardening

When is peach season? I heard it is summer but I swear I remember peaches being in season through October? Could you provide me information about peaches in the fall?

Comment: Welcome! Just to clarify: Is this a gardening or cooking question?

Comment: I’d say more of a gardening question because it isn’t a cooking question

Comment: To give a good answer we would need to know what part of the world you are in

Comment: Check the websites of some fruit growers near you who sell direct to consumers.  For a Colorado example see elafamilyfarms.com.  Ela's lists typical dates by variety for their location.  And OH their peaches!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the variety, there is a wide range of maturity times. Orchards will plant several varietys to get a long season It also depends on your location. I am in zone 8 so there are few peaches that will bear fruit with our short "chill" period , nothing that will ripen much past July last time I looked.

Comment: What about peaches in states like Idaho, Utah, New Jersey, New York, Vermont, Virginia and North Carolina? Don’t those peaches last through October?